# Displaying error message "Email not valid" but still saving to database file

Tags: c#, wpf

can anyone help me for this problem. I have three text boxes in c# WPF (windows presentation foundation). I am displaying error message when Email text box not have valid email by pressing button but all the data from other text boxes including email text box is saving to my database file. What I should to do to stop saving data if error message pop up. Many thanks.

```
 Regex regMail = new Regex(@"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");

        if (regMail.IsMatch(mailID.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email ID, Please enter \nvalid Email ID.");

        }

        Email email = new Email();

        string emailAdd = mailID.Text;
        string phone =    phoneBox.Text;
        string messageEmail = email.Text;

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Lia\mail.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine(emailAdd + phone + messageEmail);

        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't save anything to a database...

Comment: Implement proper validation, and check validity before storing to db.

Comment: I am saving data to .txt file using System.IO.StreamWriter. I have problem with stop saving when any error message popup from invalid textbox. I hope this is understandable.

Comment: The code you have shown so far is very incomplete, can you add the code where you are validating the email address, and saving to the .txt file?

Comment: @codemyway: *"I am saving data to .txt file"* - Not in the code shown you aren't.  What you're showing us is called an "`if` statement".  It examines a condition, and if that condition is `true` it executes the first block of code.  If it's `false` it executes the second block of code (the "`else`" block).  That's all it does.  If you've somehow reached the inescapable conclusion that the C# implementation of `if` *must* be broken because the rest of *your code* *must* be correct, then we can not help you with the problem you face.  Because it's not a technical problem.

Comment: Please see I added some line of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all of your code is *outside* of your `if` block.  So it's going to execute every time, regardless of the condition.

Put the code *in* the `if` block:

```
Regex regMail = new Regex(@"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");

if (regMail.IsMatch(mailID.Text))
{
    Email email = new Email();

    string emailAdd = mailID.Text;
    string phone =    phoneBox.Text;
    string messageEmail = email.Text;

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Lia\mail.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine(emailAdd + phone + messageEmail);

    file.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email ID, Please enter \nvalid Email ID.");
}
```